# Consumer Surplus

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-surplus, producer-surplus, surplus

Is there a case where the consumer surplus being negative does not mean that the producer surplus increases? Is it true that as consumer surplus increases, producer surplus decreases and vice versa?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two situations:

(i) a price so high that no consumer buys a good,

(ii) the market price at which supply and demand are equal.

CS=PS=0 in situation (i) and CS>0 and PS>0 in situation (ii).

If you move from (i) to (ii) CS increases and PS as well.

If you move from (ii) to (i) PS decreases and so does CS.

If consumers cannot be forced to buy, the CS is non-negative.